# How to convert mmddyyyy to datetime String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#

I tried

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
DateTime.ParseExact("01012014", "mm/dd/yyyy", culture);
```

but I get string is invalid datetime `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: Look at your format - it has slashes. Your value doesn't. Also, `mm` is minutes, not months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either remove slashes from expected datetime format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01012014", "MMddyyyy", culture);
```

Or add slashes to your input string:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/2014", "MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
```

Also if you want to parse first `01` as a month then you need to use `MM`, because `mm` is used for minutes.

Check out MSDN: [Custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That will parse to a number of *minutes*, not months.

Comment: Rightly so, still question haven't explicitly noted that OP wants to parse months not minutes :P After all `01` is both valid month and minute. Edited nonetheless, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You tell c# that the format is `mm/dd/yyyy`, **WITH** `/` characters, and then supply a string which has absolutely NO `/` characters in it at all.

Basically you're telling c# you're providing an apple, but really hand over an banana.

Comment: equally important you are telling it the first item is a minute not a month a month is MM not mm